# Proof of a bijection of groups

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

Say $G,H$ are finite groups. If I have surjective homomorphisms $G\stackrel{\psi}{\to}H\stackrel{\phi}{\to}G$ such that this composition is the identity, then can we see that $\psi$ is a bijection from the fact that $\text{ker}(\psi)\subset \text{ker}(\phi\circ\psi)=\{e_G\}$ and hence the kernel of $\psi$ is trivial and $\psi$ is an isomorphism right?

I think I never used the finiteness also, so I suppose this holds for arbitrary groups?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need finiteness.

For functions on sets, if you have $A\stackrel{\psi}{\to}B\stackrel{\phi}{\to}A$ such that the composition is the identity of $A$, then $\phi$ is surjective and $\psi$ is injective.

If you then add that $\psi$ is surjective, then $\psi$ is a bijection.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't used finiteness. However, if you didn't know before the fact your homomorphisms were surjective, finiteness would definitely come in handy to show the map was surjective.